# Can multiple go routines hinder variables in a same function?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

My question might be dumb but please bear with me. If two go-routines are calling the same function, will they share variables in that function? Is it safe to declare variables inside the function and use freely?

```
func main() {
 go func1(1)
 go func1(2)
}

func func1(a int) {
 something := a
 // do something
}
```

In the above code when two go-routines are calling same function will they hinder with the variable declaration of each other? Will the value of `something` change if the go routines are not in order or something?

Comment: *"will they share variables in that function?"* -- No, not unless those variables were declared in an outer scope of the function.

Comment: @mkopriva
Can you please give a little bit of explanation on this? I am new to Go so I may require some sort of elaboration. Thanks

Comment: *"Is it safe to declare variables inside the function and use freely?"* -- Yes.

Comment: Go does not support variable hoisting, nor does it have dynamic scoping. Go is lexically scoped using blocks. An identifier declared in a block is available only to that block and any of its nested blocks. Just because a block can be executed more than once, it does not mean that the identifiers declared in that block can be shared between executions. That would be quite unmanageable, especially for a "concurrency oriented" language like Go.

Comment: @mkopriva
Thanks for the elaborate explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`will they hinder the variable declaration` - no. essentially it's a function.. so if you're declaring the variable inside the function.. there won't be any issues and it works normally.

but if the variable is not declared inside the function but outside the scope of the function then the order of the go routines will hinder the value
for example

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var something int

func test(a int) {
    something += a
    fmt.Println("something", something)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Testing Something")
    go test(20)
    go test(3)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // crude way without using channels or waitgroup.
}
```

Comment: okay so is it safe to say that these variables inside the function are generated in context of the go-routines itself?

Comment: yes, it's scoped inside that function block. check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-go/ for more clarity